# When will Amazon RDS suport MariaDB > 10.6?

Tags: mariadb, amazon-rds

RDS has historically added support for new mariadb releases within a year, but they seem stuck on 10.6 and haven't added the new 10.7, 10.8, 10.9, 10.10, 10.11, which are all GA.

MariaDB did change their policy and only provide 1 year support for most releases, the exception being 10.6 and 10.11 which are designated LTS.  Was Amazon waiting for 10.11 and just haven't had enough time yet to release it?

Trying to make upgrade plans, but it's hard to do so without any information from Amazon on their plans.

Comment: How can we possibly answer this question?
You should ask Amazon.

Comment: @Massimo totally understood, but I'm pretty sure someone out there has already done that and can share.  Even more interesting if there are several such someones who heard different things.

Answer (score 1):

A guess...

Beginning with 10.6, MariaDB switched to a release pattern that mimics the Linux release schedule.  It includes:

- More frequent releases.
- Some releases are "LTS", meaning "Long Term Support" for 5 years.
- The intermediate releases are supported for only one year.

10.6 was LTS (GA: 6 Jul 2021);
10.11 (GA: 16 Feb 2023) is the next LTS.

https://mariadb.org/about/#maintenance-policy

https://endoflife.date/mariadb

So, I guess that Amazon is working on upgrading to 10.11 as we speak.

Comment: just so very slowly?